# Call different events based on user input style in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `div` which contains an input element to enter some values. These values are added just above the `div` as a list element upon pressing enter or `onFocusOut` event. To this point it is fine. But if user types some value and does not press enter and directly clicks on save button, the `onFocusOut` function for that `div` should not be called.  Instead it should take that typed value and call some `save` function. Do you have any suggestion on how to detect it?

My code snippet is here:

JS:

```
 divInput.onkeypress = function (event){
                return someTestFunc();
    }
    
    
    divInput.tabIndex="-1";

    $(divInput).focusout(function (e) {
        if ($(this).find(e.relatedTarget).length == 0) {
            addToList();
        }
    });
```

Comment: use `.blur()` instead of `.focusout()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a very delicate solution, but you could use a setTimeout before adding the item to the list and clear the setTimeout on save.button click.
Try this:

```
var $saveButton = $('#exampleButton')[0],
    $divInput = $('#exampleInput')[0],
    timedEvent = -1;

$($saveButton).on('click', function(event){
    if(timedEvent) {
        clearTimeout(timedEvent)
    }
    alert('not add to list & save');
})


$divInput.tabIndex="-1";

$($divInput).on('focusout', function(e) {
    timedEvent = window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(this).find(e.relatedTarget).length == 0) {
            alert('add to list');
        }
    }, 200);
});
```

Check this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/turh61t9/1/)